# XML Deserialize just wont work: Returning empty Records

Tags: c#, xml

Below is my specimen and code. I just cant figure where the problem is and I'm stuck for days....SOS please

MY XML and ENTITY BELOW

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<root>
<record>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <NAME>YOUSUF YSAI</NAME>
</record>
<record>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <NAME>MOHAMMED YSAI </NAME>
</record>
</root>


  public class Root
  {
    public List<Record> records {get; set;}
  }

  public class Record
  {
    public string ID {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
  }
```

My XML Deserialize Extension Method:

```
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this string xml)
    {
        XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
        xRoot.ElementName = "root";
        //  xRoot.Namespace = "";
        xRoot.IsNullable = true;

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T),xRoot);
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;


        using (StringReader textReader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings))
            {
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how I'm calling the Deserialize

```
    string xml = File.ReadAllText(file.Directory.FullName + "\\" + filename);
    Root root = xml.Deserialize<Root>();
```

No exception is returned but more annoying no Record is returned as well...

Comment: The serialization is case sensitive.  The class names and tag names have to be exactly the same.  You have Record and record.

Comment: And `Name` and `NAME`

Comment: Find my answer @olivedejohnson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your Class with this:-

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "record")]
    public List<Record> records { get; set; }
}
public class Record
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "NAME")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Whole Working Example:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data = File.ReadAllText("D://check.xml");//your xml code is in file name check.xml
            var streamdata = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data ?? ""));
            Stream st = streamdata;
            Root ro = new Root();
            XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
            ro=(Root)xml.Deserialize(st);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "record")]
        public List<Record> records { get; set; }
    }

    public class Record
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID")]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "NAME")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updating the POCO with the [XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")] Attribute did the trick. Thanks

Comment: Ok great @oliverdejohnson